# Why use  /*, */ around arguments and why use >>> when extracting the length of an array?

Tags: javascript

I was looking in the javascript reference manual on the indexOf page at [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) site, and noticed a few things in their implementation code of indexOf, I hope somebody can explain to me.

To save everybody a round trip to the mozilla site, here is the entire function:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)
{
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/)
  {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;

    var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
    from = (from < 0)
         ? Math.ceil(from)
         : Math.floor(from);
    if (from < 0)
      from += len;

    for (; from < len; from++)
    {
      if (from in this &&
          this[from] === elt)
        return from;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

What I do not understand is the **`/*, from*/`** in the function declaration, and the zero-fill right shift **`>>>`** in the extracting of the length of the array (**`var len = this.length >>> 0;`**).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `/*, from */` is a commented out parameter. However it looks like it has been left in the comments to show that this parameter can **optionally** be specified for the function.

```
var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
```

I believe that `arguments[1]` would be the `from` value if passed in.

> The arguments array is especially
>   useful with functions that can be
>   called with a variable number of
>   arguments, or with more arguments than
>   they were formally declared to accept. http://www.devguru.com/Technologies/Ecmascript/Quickref/arguments.html

The `>>>` is an unsigned right shift. It's being used here to convert a potentially signed number `length` into an unsigned number.

[Extract from Professional JavaScript for Web Developers](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=f_2R9ra2PjEC&pg=PA42&lpg=PA42&dq=javascript%20unsigned%20right%20shift&source=bl&ots=jM4Y4Y3ZDS&sig=fbHEe14PUaCYf1Wfq5TIX2tlW0I&hl=en&ei=4aWjSrXRJ56UjAfKuJmYDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3#v=onepage&q=javascript%20unsigned%20right%20shift&f=false)

http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/jsoprurshift.htm

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now. I did not realize that the length property could be anything but unsigned, javascript puzzles me at times :)

Answer (score 3):

The `/*, from */` is an optional parameter. Notice `var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;` after that. If a second parameter was passed in the function call, the variable from will set to it.

Not sure about the unsigned right shift. Doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

The `/*, from*/` in the function declaration is just a comment by the author to say, that there’s a second optional parameter named *from*. It’s wrote as a comment so that it isn’t part of the signature (`Array.prototype.indexOf.length` returns 1).

And the right shift is probably used to always get an integer value of `this.length`.