# What does x >>> 0 do?

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What good does zero-fill bit-shifting by 0 do? (a >>> 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081987/what-good-does-zero-fill-bit-shifting-by-0-do-a-0)

I've been trying out some functional programming concepts in a project of mine and I was reading about `Array.prototype.map`, which is new in ES5 and looks like this:

```
Array.prototype.map = function(fun) {
    "use strict";
    if (this === void 0 || this === null) {
        throw new TypeError();
    }
    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun !== "function") {
        throw new TypeError();
    }
    var res = new Array(len);
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (i in t) {
            res[i] = fun.call(thisp, t[i], i, t);
        }
    }
    return res;
};
```

What I'm wondering is why it's doing `t.length >>> 0`. Because it doesn't seem to do anything. `x >>> 0 //-> x`! (as long as x is a number, obviously)

Also, note that I don't know how bitwise operators work.

Comment: and lots of others http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822350/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474815/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385491/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348438/ These are easy to find only when the first one can be found >_>.

Comment: @KennyTM ~ Good duplicates if you know what the names of the things are ... ;)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`x >>> 0` performs a logical (unsigned) right-shift of 0 bits, which is equivalent to a no-op. However, before the right shift, it must convert the `x` to an unsigned 32-bit integer. Therefore, the overall effect of `x >>> 0` is convert `x` into a 32-bit unsigned integer.

This ensures `len` is a nonnegative number.

```
js> 9 >>> 0
9
js> "9" >>> 0
9
js> "95hi" >>> 0
0
js> 3.6 >>> 0
3
js> true >>> 0
1
js> (-4) >>> 0
4294967292
```

Comment: Can you please explain why something.length would be less than 0?

Comment: @Pratik And why would it be `true`? There's probably no real-world reason for it. But if it happened (by accident eg.), it would break the `.map`. Example code: `Array.prototype.map.call({length:-2},f)`

Comment: Why would someone use Number(pos) >>> 0? Wouldn't pos >>> 0 be all you need?